# I can't create relationship in MS Access with dropdown based off query

Tags: ms-access, relationship, dropdown

I'm trying to do the following but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a master table of employees that have a status condition (active, inactive).
I have a query that filters out the inactive employees leaving only active.
I have a work records table that has a dropdown using the active employees query.

The problem is that I when I do this a relationship between the employee master table and work records does not get created. I manually linked them but it still does not work.
When I pull the employee list straight from the master table it works just fine. Relationship is created and I'm able to see the linked records to each employee.

Please help, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Edit question to show query SQL statement. Combobox RowSource can be a statement, do not have to reference a query object. What are the combobox properties: ControlSource, RowSource, ColumnCount, ColumnWidths, BoundColumn. "Does not work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? This is a design issue, not programming, therefore no code to analyze and not really an appropriate question for SO. Should be data entry via form, not tables.

Comment: Also, what are data types of linking key fields?